# I've been having this issue for a while now, and I'm new to flutter, and the output shows a null check operator

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[This is my code when i use null initialization its giving me a error of Null check operator on document!exists condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Qlx.png)

Comment: Can you include code with details instead of code-image?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. document can have null value, when it is null, trying to use it will cause exception. You need to check null before using it.
2. Never put network call or similar method inside Build. Build is designed to call whenever Flutter want, without your controll.